# The Witness audiologs - are the conversations "real"?

Tags: the-witness

In The Witness there are orange-coloured audiologs underground. They often feature dialogue or monologue by what seems to be the game's developers. Are these actual recordings of the development process that they put in, or was this all also scripted and acted out? I tried searching the Internet, but could not find anything. Have the authors ever commented on this?

**Added:** I'm not really interested in fan speculations. The game is deliberately very ambiguous so there's bound to be lots of those in all directions. I'm wondering what the makers of the game themselves have said.

And if they haven't, then if there is some fan speculation that makes such a strong case that it has become the prevailing opinion in the community, I'll take that too.

Otherwise we can just leave it as "ambiguous", which is, I think, the best word to describe the entire game. :)

Answer (score 2):

From [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheWitness/comments/hznui6/sources_of_the_audio_logs/):

> In the install directory, check [en.subtitles](https://pastebin.com/raw/dvfPQ6VG). The subtitles for each audio log have an associated tag, for instance: feynman marks the start of an audio log that comes from a [Feynman lecture](https://www.informationphilosopher.com/solutions/scientists/feynman/past_and_future.html).
>
> EDIT: Actually those subtitles aren't for an audio log, they're for the 2nd underground theater video. But the audio logs are in there too.

From [Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/210970/discussions/4/458606877326632562/):

> In some way, the audio logs are meant to service the story

So yes they are scripted, they are part of the storyline!

Comment: Isn't that all still just fan speculation?

Comment: At the moment, yes it is quite ambiguous, I'll keep searching though (pretty sure its still scripted) @Vilx-

Answer (score 1):

These are scripted, and part of the storyline of the game.

Comment: Do you have any sources?

Comment: @Vilx-: If you listen to all the conversations it should be obvious. **Major spoilers ahead:** they are talking about the game you're playing, but in the game's universe the game is a Matrix-like virtual reality thing meant for rehabilitation, not a PC puzzle game controlled with mouse-and-keyboard. They even show the "real world" (in the game's universe) in the secret ending.

Comment: I've listened to all the underground logs and am hunting down a few remaining above-ground logs, but it didn't strike me as a matrix-like story. The underground logs sounded like regular conversations that actual developers might have in the process of developing the game. Yes, it mentioned "a trip to the island" once, but I think that could also be taken to mean just playing the game. All that said, the game is, of course, very ambiguous, and the matrix-like explanation is just as plausible.